# Swift Range Operator with two unknown values

Tags: ios, swift, loops

If I have two unknown values, lets say `x` and `y`, what is the best way loop through all of the values **between** between those values?

For example, given the values `x = 0` and `y = 5` I would like to do something with the values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. The result could exclude 0 and 5 if this is simpler.

Using Swift's Range operator, I *could* do something like this:

```
for i in x...y {
    // Do something with i
}
```

Except I do not know if `x` or `y` is the greater value.

The [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID73) for Range Operators states:

> The closed range operator (`a...b`) defines a range that runs from `a` to `b`, and includes the values `a` and `b`. The value of `a` must not be greater than `b`.

There are a number of solutions here. A pretty straight forward one is:

```
let diff = y - x

for i in 0...abs(diff) {
    let value = min(x, y) + i
    // Do something with value
}
```

Is there a better, or more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the most explicit way of writing it would be:

```
for i in min(a, b)...max(a, b) {
    // Do something with i
}
```

To exclude the first and last value, you can increment your lower limit and use the Swift `..<` syntax:

```
let lowerLimit = min(a, b) + 1
let upperLimit = max(a, b)

for i in lowerLimit..<upperLimit {
    // Do something with i
}
```